# Scaling tailiwnd font size in reactjs globally

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

In my react app, using tailwind css, is there any global settings i can adjust so that my fonts scale with the screen size. For example, at screens larger than 2xl, i would like my text-sm to be 1 rem instead of the default 0.875rem

Comment: Is using media queries an option?

Comment: @Dimitar sure..what does your solution look like?

Comment: @media only screen and (min-width: 1234px) { /*Replace 1234 with tailwind's 2xl screen size begin */
    .text-sm { font-size: 1rem !important; }
}

This essentially overwrites tailwinds' `text-sm` class on screen sizes larger than `1234px`. You can do `min-width` and `max-width` in the media query as well to make it in range.

Comment: Thnaks, @Dimitar, works..just have to add the px when specifying the min width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS you can add:

```
@media (min-width: 1536px) {
    .text-sm {
        font-size: 1rem !important;
    }
}
```

This will essentially overwrite the `font-size` property of any element which is tagget with the `text-sm` class.

The `1536px` comes from the [official Tailwind references which explain responsive design in detail](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design).

You need to add `!important` in order to force the CSS to apply.